# How to submit dynamically generated forms by pressing Enter key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

My website have a comment system. Website is built with django framework, and I am loading all post's comment with loop.

I am able to add comment text in text box of first post, rest of the posts does not submitting comment, I know this is due to dynamically generated id's of every form and comment boxes.

I am also able to submit dynamically generated comments boxes of all posts when I have submit button in form

But I want to submit these comments when user press Enter button such as Facebook comment.

Below is the comment form code for every post, I have discarded rest of the code that is related to showing posts.

```
     {% for i in posts %}

     ///Rest of the code for posts...

       <form method="POST" id= 'post-form'>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="comment-block">
            <img class="img-circle" src="{% static 'mysite/images/avatar.png' %}">
            <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{i.post_id}}" hidden>
            <input name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{i.user_id}}" hidden>
            <span class="username"><a href="#">{{ i.user_name }}</a>
            <input type="text" name="comment_text" id="comment_text" class="comment-text form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Write a comment...">

            <span></span>
          </div>
        </form>
     {% endfor %}
```

Below is the jquery code that I am using to access dynamically generated forms

```
  $(this).find('#comment_text').keyup(function(e){

    if(e.keyCode ==13){
        comment_text = $(this).find('#comment_text').val();
        user_id = $(this).find('#user_id').val();
        post_id = $(this).find('#post_id').val();
      }
     }
   });
```

Any help will be appreciated, If you have any question let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have elements with the same `id`, `id="comment_text"` is repeated for every form, you should either remove this attribute or make it dynamic (`id="comment_text_{{ post.id }}"` for example)

Then you need to change your selector that attaches the event handler so that it selects **all** the text fields rather than just one (which happens when you use an id), [here's how you can do it by matching the `name` attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[name="comment_text"]').keyup(function() {...})
```

To have the event trigger for comments that may be dynamically added to the page you need to use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#comment_container').on('keyup', 'input[name="comment_text"]', function() {...})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response `$(function(){
$('input[name="comment_text"]').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    alert("hello enter");
    alert($(this).find('input').eq(1).val());
  }
});`  I am able to submit every form by pressing enter but could not get data of every input field.

Comment: I also got all fields by the following code `$('form').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      //alert($(this).find('input').eq(0).val());
      var token = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
      var post_id = $(this).find('input').eq(1).val();
      var user_id = $(this).find('input').eq(2).val();
      var comment = $(this).find('input').eq(3).val(); `  but when I submit form, it through exception of Maximum call stack reached.